# Degree of functions on a curve that are no zero divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a noetherian commutative ring of dimension one which is reduced. Moreover, $R$ is free of rank $n$ over the polynomial ring $k[x]$ where $k$ is a field.

**The background:**
$R = \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is the affine coordinate ring where $U \subseteq X$ is an affine everywhere dense open subset of $X$, a reduced projective curve over $k$ with finite surjective morphism onto $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.

Fix a basis $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ of $R$ over $k[x]$. For any $y \in R$ let $\deg(y)$ be the maximal degree of its coefficients regarding the fixed basis of $R$. Let $P_1,\ldots,P_r$ be the minimal primes of $R$ such that $\cup_i P_i \neq R$. Thus there are elements of $R$ not being zero divisors.

> What can we say about the upper bound on the minimum of the degrees of regular elements of $R$? What is $$\min_{y \in R}\ \{ \deg(y) \mid y \notin \cup_i P_i \}?$$

I am looking for some bounds in terms of $n$ and $g$, where $g$ is the arithmetic genus of $X$. Bounds in terms of the genera of the irreducible components belonging to the $P_i$ are also welcome.

Does anyone have some helpful references or ideas how to approach this kind of problem?

---

**Remark:**
Originally, the question arised in terms of elements of fractional ideals $I$ of $R$, which are also free modules over $k[x]$ and do not only consist of zero divisors. Hence the question above is the case $I = R$.

Comment: If $k$ is infinite, then the lower bound is zero, since for general constants $a_i\in k$, $y=\sum a_iy_i\not\in \cup_i P_i$.

Comment: @Mohan Could you elaborate that?

Comment: Could you show that not all $y_i$ can be in one minimal prime ideal? Then show that the elements in the $k$-vector space generated by $y_i$s which lie in a fixed $P_i$ is a proper subspace. Finally, finite union of proper subspaces can not be all of the vector space, since $k$ is infinite.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks. Do you know how to proceed for a finite field $k$?