# Example of set of zero divisors whose linear combinations are again zero divisors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a finite field. Let $k[x] \subseteq R$ where $R$ is a noetherian, onedimensional and reduced ring such that $R$ is finite free over $k[x]$ (in particular, the polynomials in $x$ are no zero divisors in $R$).

> Could you give me an example of a set $Z \subseteq R$ with $\lvert Z\rvert \geq 2$ such that $Z$ is $k[x]$-linearly independent and, moreover, every $k$-linear combination of its elements is a zero divisor?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=k[y], B=k[z]$ and let $R=A\times B$. We have an inclusion $k[x]\subset R$ where $x\mapsto (y^2,z^2)$. Then, $R$ is free over $k[x]$ with basis $(1,0), (0,1), (y,0), (0,z)$. Take $Z=\{(1,0), (y,0)\}$. Then every $k[x]$ linear combination of elements of $Z$ is a zero divisor, not just $k$-linear combinations. Every one such is killed by the non-zero element $(0,1)$.

Comment: This is funny, because I am asking this to eventually come up with an example of such a set which additionally produces (via a $k[x]$-linear combination) a regular element. Do you know a modification of your example which also copes with this?

Comment: Don't we have $\dim(R) > 1$?

Comment: No, $\dim R=1$, it has two minimal primes generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and the quotients are both isomorphic to polynomial ring in one variable.

Comment: @windsheaf Can you explain why you want such an example? Here is an example. Let the base field $k$ be a field of two elements. Let $R=k[u,v]/uv(u+v)$ and let $x=u+v^2$. I will let you check that $k[x]\subset R$ is integral. Take $Z=\{u,v\}$.

Comment: I would like to see that the lower bound of the degree of functions on a curve that are regular, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797943/degree-of-functions-on-a-curve-that-are-no-zero-divisors is not necessarily zero as in the infinite field case. And for this to work I need a basis consisting of zero divisors such that every $k$-linear combination is again a zero divisor such that there is some $k[x]$-linerar combination providing a regular element.

Comment: @windsheaf The example above has all these. $u,v$ are $k[x]$ linearly independent, every $k$-linear combination is a zero divisor and $k[x]$-linear combinations are in general not a zero divisor. I will let you check its degree, as you call it.